# Is There A Name For Total Personality Disorder(A+B+C)?

Tags: personality, personality-disorder, mental-illness

I've been researching what sort of mental illness I am contending with because years of working with doctors has been a practice of throwing darts in the dark and missing every target. Various psychological disorders have been toyed with and I've been labeled clinically depressed, general anxiety, bipolar, borderline, etc, etc..

I've more or less narrowed it down to the realm of personality disorder but as I go through the clusters, A, B, and C, I can check off almost every symptom as either being present in my life to varying degrees or having been a problem in the past, some of which I've already worked through.

I am a tad frustrated with the ineffectual treatment I've received after years of concerted effort and I bristle at all the meds thrown at symptoms that missed the mark entirely and actually worsened the issue. I have always known my only biological issue had something to do with the GABA area of the brain and even then the suggestions never worked - It is exactly why I drank for most of my life, I have been sober during these years of treatment and just suffering the GABA problem.

Anyway, my illness is almost entirely psychological and I span the spectrum of personality disorder - Any idea of a name for something that encapsulates the realm of psychological personality illness?